# How to have an array of images side by side using css/html

Tags: html, css

I am using css/html and trying to get a sort-of "array" of different images smack side by side similar to this:

In the css file:

```
#header_index   {background:#FFFFFF url('image1.jpg') repeat-x 10px 10px; padding:20px; height:240px; }
```

In the html file:

```
<div id="header_index"></div>
```

That sticks image1.jpg side-by-side horizontally.

What I want is to have the same exact look, but with multiple images.

How can I get an "array" or whatever of images so that it's image1.jpgimage2.jpgimage3.jpg with no border at all. I tried using a table and divs but could not get rid of the border and besides I want to try to use the same approach that I am already using (where the image is specified in the css file).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you want 4 images on each row. Therefore, there will be 4 columns and each column will take up 25% of the width.

```
<div class="col-1-4"></div>
<div class="col-1-4"></div>
<div class="col-1-4"></div>
<div class="col-1-4"></div>
```

Let's set there width in the css and float the div to the left so they are not in the flow of the document.

```
.col-1-4{
  width:25%;
  float:left;
}
```

Now, we're going to add an image inside each div. Here's one example div.

```
<div class="col-1-4">
  <img src="(PUT URL OF IMAGEHERE)"/>
</div>
```

As you can tell, the image is larger than the div. So let's constrain the width for all images to fit inside the column div.

```
img{
  max-width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Outstanding. I agree not to embed so much in the css file. I am using an open source template that I downloaded and that is the way it was set up. However, I got it to work (without the image URLs in the css file) and it works exactly as I was hoping. Awesome. Thank you very much for the assistance.

Comment: @TimZych no problem man. If this helped, check it off as the answer! Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

Simple example:

```
div { display: inline-block; }
```

This will make all your containers render side by side. Even better if you add a class:

```
<div class="image" id="image1"></div>
<div class="image" id="image2"></div>

.image { display: inline-block; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't load images like that in the CSS, unless they really are background images. If you need them to be background images, you can use the same code below but you'll have to use the 'background-position' property to move the images around inside the container.

I would set the img or container element to inline-block. If you use a container, you can make the images take up the same space, regardless of the actual image size, by 'cropping' the images inside the container. Set the container to overflow: hidden, and display: inline-block. Make sure you set your img elements to display: block as well. Then just list out the containers with each image inside.

```
div {
    display: inline-block;
    /* crops images */
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    /* makes abs positioned images stay inside container */
    position: relative;
}

div img {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    /* center the image */
    left: 50%;
    height: 50%
}
```

If you don't want to use relative/absolute positioning you can set the position of the images with negative margins, but I prefer rel/abs positioning.